# Getting extra bytes in received file using java scoket

Tags: java, multithreading

I have implemented a file transfer program using java socket. In this program, a file is sent from the client and its then downloaded in the Server. The program works almost correctly but the problem is the length of the received byte is always greater than the byte length sent from the client. for example, I sent 678888589 bytes from the client, but when I check the length of the received file at the server, I got 678925260 bytes. And for that reason, I am getting different checksum on the server side.

Here is my code:
Client Class:

```
public class Client  
{ 
    final static int ServerPort = 1234; 
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 50;
    private static byte[] buffer;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException  
    { 
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        Socket s1 = new Socket(ip, ServerPort); 
        DataOutputStream dos1 = new DataOutputStream(s1.getOutputStream());
        SendMessage message = new SendMessage(s1, "test.mp4",dos1);
        Thread t = new Thread(message); 
        System.out.println("Adding this client to active client list"); 
        t.start();
    }
  }
}

class SendMessage implements Runnable{
    String file_name;
    Socket s;
    public final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 50;
    private byte[] buffer;
    DataOutputStream dos;

public SendMessage(Socket sc,String file_name,DataOutputStream dos) {
    this.file_name = file_name;
    this.s=sc;
    buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    this.dos = dos;
}

@Override
public void run() { 
    File file = new File(file_name);
    try {
        sendFile(file, dos);
        dos.close();
        while(true) {

        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

} 


public void sendFile(File file, DataOutputStream dos) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE+1];
    if(dos!=null&&file.exists()&&file.isFile())
    {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        dos.writeLong(file.length());

      System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        int read = 0;
        int totalLength = 0;
        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            dos.write(buffer);
            totalLength +=read;
            System.out.println("length "+read);
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println("File successfully sent! "+totalLength);
    }
}

}
```

Server Class

```
// Server class 
public class Server 
{ 

    // Vector to store active clients 
    static Vector<ClientHandler> ar = new Vector<>(); 

    // counter for clients 
    static int i = 0; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    { 
        // server is listening on port 1234 
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234); 

        Socket s; 

        // running infinite loop for getting 
        // client request 
        while (true) 
        { 
            // Accept the incoming request 
            s = ss.accept(); 

            System.out.println("New client request received : " + s); 

            // obtain input and output streams 
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); 

            System.out.println("Creating a new handler for this client..."); 

            // Create a new handler object for handling this request. 
            ClientHandler mtch = new ClientHandler(s,"client " + i, dis, dos); 

            // Create a new Thread with this object. 
            Thread t = new Thread(mtch); 

            System.out.println("Adding this client to active client list"); 

            // add this client to active clients list 
            ar.add(mtch); 

            // start the thread. 
            t.start(); 

            // increment i for new client. 
            // i is used for naming only, and can be replaced 
            // by any naming scheme 
            i++; 

        } 
    } 
} 

// ClientHandler class 
class ClientHandler implements Runnable 
{ 
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); 
    private String name; 
    final DataInputStream dis; 
    final DataOutputStream dos; 
    Socket s; 
    boolean isloggedin; 
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*50;
    private byte[] buffer;

    // constructor 
    public ClientHandler(Socket s, String name, 
            DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos) { 
        this.dis = dis; 
        this.dos = dos; 
        this.name = name; 
        this.s = s; 
        this.isloggedin=true; 
        buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    } 

    @Override
    public void run() { 
        String received;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;
        String outputFile = "out_"+this.name+".mp4";
        BufferedInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
//      while (true) 
//      { 
            try
            { 


                long length = -1;
                length = dis.readLong();
                if(length!=-1)System.out.println("length "+length);

//              String checkSum = dis.readUTF();
//              System.out.println(checkSum);

                int len=0;
                long totalLength = 0;

//              int len = 0;
                while ((len = in.read(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    totalLength+=len;
//                  if(len<BUFFER_SIZE)break;
//                  System.out.println("length "+len);
                    if(len<=0)break;
                }

                File file = new File(outputFile);

                System.out.println("total length1 "+totalLength+ " dif "+(totalLength-length));

                System.out.println("output length "+file.length());         

            } catch (IOException e) { 

                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 

    }

    private static String checksum(String filepath, MessageDigest md) throws IOException {

        // file hashing with DigestInputStream
        try (DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(new FileInputStream(filepath), md)) {
            while (dis.read() != -1) ; //empty loop to clear the data
            md = dis.getMessageDigest();
        }

        // bytes to hex
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : md.digest()) {
            result.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        return result.toString();

    }
}
```

It would be great if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong. also, how can I verify the checksum on serverside. Another issue is the server side code get blocked in this block.

```
while ((len = in.read(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    System.out.println("length "+len);
    if(len<=0)break;
}
```

It can't break the loop unless the client is disconnected. Although the file is recieved properly.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You made a small mistake on the client code.  You were writing out the full buffer instead of what is read from the file.

```
        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            dos.write(buffer,0,read);
            totalLength += read;
            System.out.println("length " + read);
        }
```

Comment: it worked! thanks. Thanks. will it be possible to tell me about the last part? it can't break the file receiving loop unless the socket is closed. But if the socket is closed I can't send ack to the client.

Comment: That one is more of a design problem.  after connecting the client can send how much data it will send before sending.  and once the server reads that amount of data you can stop the loop and send that ack.